# Meaning of principal definitions of SR in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I have just started with relativistic quantum mechanics in my advanced quantum theory class and we only had a very short intermezzo on special relativity. I feel like I don’t have enough knowledge on the formalisim of SR which is here being merged with QM. At the moment I’m just handling SR as a condition that must hold and thats it. Two fundamental questions that I don’t fully understand are the following:

1. Why is the Schrödinger equation not covariant (aka *form invariant under Lorentz transformations*)?

Us was told that the reason is the order of the time and space derivative not matching. Indeed, I see a certain connection between that fact and the defined scalar product, but the argument seems still a bit vague to me. And is the word “form” the synonym of the “scalar product”?

2. Why is the scalar product defined as: $x\cdot y = x_\mu y^\mu = x_0y_0 - \vec{x}\vec{y}$ ? What is the intuition behind the minus signs in the metric tensor? How do I know at a given scalar product $e^{-ik\cdot x}$ which of the both ($x$ or $k$) is the covariant one? Or is it always defined to be the left one?

I think the best would just be a recommendation of a good book, which would answer questions that go in this direction without going too deep in SR…

Comment: There is no "too deep in SR". It is almost always taught in too little. And yes, you should just read a good book on SR

Comment: I recommend Chapter 14 of my EM textbook, which should get you ready for going further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to the 2nd question.  Starting from the end, it's $\exp(i(wt-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}))$ and the covariance is built into the sub-expression $(\omega/c,\vec{k})\cdot(ct,\vec{x})=\omega t-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}$ which is the Lorentz inner-product of two four-vectors.  Any expression derived from Lorentz inner-products of four-vectors is automatically covariant in special relativity.  In Quantum theory you also have the relation $(E/c,\vec{p}) = \hbar(\omega/c,\vec{k})$ which is between four-vectors.

As for the signature of the Lorentz inner product.  In inner products on a plane you have the Euclidean inner product $(x_1,y_1)\cdot (x_2,y_2)=x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2$.  This inner product is preserved by the group $SO(2)$ of matrices
$$R_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$
where 'preserve' means $v^\top O v = v^\top v$ for all $O\in SO(2)$ and $v\in\Bbb{R}^2$.

You also have the hyperbolic inner product $(x_1, y_1) \cdot (x_2, y_2)=x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2$.  This inner product is preserved by the group of hyperbolic rotations
$$H_\psi=\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(\psi)&-\sinh(\psi)\\
-\sinh(\psi)&\cosh(\psi)
\end{pmatrix}$$
and this is where the connection to special relativity is.  Because a Lorentz boost, say in direcion $x$ is given by the transformation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
ct'\\x'
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma\beta\\
-\gamma\beta& \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
ct\\x
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\beta = v/c$ and $\gamma=(1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$.  There is then a unique $\psi_v$ (called the rapidity) such that $\beta = \tanh(\psi_v)$, $\gamma=\cosh(\psi_v)$ and $\gamma\beta = \sinh(\psi_v)$ and then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma\beta\\
-\gamma\beta& \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(\psi_v) & -\sinh(\psi_v)\\
-\sinh(\psi_v)& \cosh(\psi_v)
\end{pmatrix}=H_{\psi_v}
$$
So a Lorentz boost transformation is a hyperbolic rotation!  Now consider the inner product
$$ct_1 ct_2 - x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2 - z_1 z_2$$
This is an inner product of a four-dimensional space $(ct,x,y,z)$.  It has three Euclidean planes $xy, yz, zx$ where the metric signature is $(-1,-1)$ which is equivalent to $(1,1)$.  It also has three hyperbolic planes $tx, ty, tz$ where the metric signature is $(1,-1)$.  So the group of transformations that preserve this inner product has a total of six one-dimensional subgroups generating it.  Three of them are Euclidean rotations in the $xy, yz, zx$ planes, and three of them are hyperbolic rotations in the $tx, ty, tz$ planes corresponding to the Lorentz boosts.  The space $\Bbb{R}^4$ with this inner product is called Minkowski space, and the group that preserves the inner product is called the Lorentz group.  Everything that happens in special relativity lives in this space, and if you formulate the physical laws using four-vectors and the Lorentz inner product, the theory is Lorentz-covariant.  It looks the same in a change of inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

The question is broad, so here is a brief answer assuming some familiarity with the summation convention.

1. For Lorentz covariance, one first has to compute how partial derivatives transform under Lorentz transformations which transform spacetime co-ordinates $(t, x, y, z)$ to $(t', x', y', z')$. The condition of Lorentz covariance of an equation is to claim that it is unchanged by Lorentz transformations. In other words, the Lorentz transformation should only amount to a relabeling of the co-ordinates (this is *form invariance* and thus not a synonym of the scalar product). This is not the case with the Schrödinger equation as it first order in time and second order in space.
2. Your question about scalar products require an understanding of what they are in the first place. A simple generalisation allows us to define the scalar product as a bilinear form, i.e,
   $$ \langle x, y \rangle_g = x^\mathrm{T} g \, y = g_{ij} \, x^i y^j = g^{ij} x_i \, y_j,$$
   where $x, y \in \mathbb{V} = \mathrm{span}\left(\{\mathbf{e}_i\}_{i \in [n]}\right).$ As a scalar product, this expression is meaningful whenever $g$ is a symmetric and non-degenerate matrix. This is in fact, the matrix representation of what is known as a *metric tensor.* In Euclidean vector spaces, $g$ is just the identity matrix. When we work with space-time, which is the natural playground for SR, we use a particular $g = \eta = \mathrm{diag}(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ as the metric. However, this is just convention as one can equivalently choose $\eta = \mathrm{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$. The metric has the property of raising or lowering the indices on a vector, $g_{ij} \, x^i = x_j$ and $g^{ij} x_i = x^j$ and as such,
   $$ \langle x, y \rangle_\eta = \eta_{\mu \nu} \, x^\mu y^\nu = x_\nu y^\nu = x^\mu y_\mu = \eta^{\mu \nu} x_\mu \, y_\nu,$$
   where we use greek indices to denote that we are working in space-time.

- Depending on the convention I choose for $\eta$, I get,
  $$ \langle x, y \rangle_\eta = \mp x_0 \, y_0 \pm x_i \, y_i = \mp x_0 \, y_0 \pm \langle x, y \rangle.$$
  As for why $\eta$ is defined in such a way, the intuition comes from what the space-time interval between any two events must be in SR.
- The components of a vector with upper indices are called *contravariant* in the literature and in a naive sense one could think of them as the components of column vectors perhaps. On the flipside, the lower indexed components are called *covariant* which one could think of as components of row vectors dual to their column vector counterparts. The metric tensor serves as the means to do switch between the two.

All that I have mentioned here is a rather naive presentation on the topics glossing over several technicalities. To be fair, a good introduction to special relativity and also the [Ricci calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus#) is a must before getting into relativistic quantum mechanics or field theory.